# Apache 2.4 SSL 1.0.1 ports conflicting

Tags: php, apache, ssl

Have an apache enviornment which is hosting a PHP based website. Having some issues configuring SSL. The httpd-ssl.conf file was initially pointing to port 443. However I changed that as I assumed it needed to point to the same port which is configured within the httpd.conf

The following are some of the important httpd.conf configurations

```
Listen 882
<virtualHost *:882>
        ServerAdmin admin@example.com
        DocumentRoot "/u/apache/htdocs/Hil"
        ServerName server1
</virtualHost>
<virtualHost *:882>
        ServerAdmin admin@example.com
        DocumentRoot "/u/apache/htdocs/Hil"
        ServerName server1
        <directory "/u/apache/htdocs/Hil">
                 Order allow,deny
           Allow from all
           # New directive needed in Apache 2.4.3:
           Require all granted
        </directory>
</virtualHost>

<IfModule mod_rewrite>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
    RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>

TraceEnable off
```

Below I have configured the httpd-ssl.conf file. I configured the ports to be on the same port at the httpd.conf, I dont know if this is correct or not.

```
Listen 882
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
SSLSessionCache        "shmcb:/u/apache/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

<VirtualHost _default_:882>

#   General setup for the virtual host
DocumentRoot "/u/apache/htdocs"
ServerName server1:882
ServerAdmin you@example.com
ErrorLog "/u/apache/logs/error_log"
TransferLog "/u/apache/logs/access_log"


SSLEngine on


SSLCertificateFile "/u/apache/conf/extra/certs/qa.cer"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/u/apache/conf/extra/certs/qa.key"
```

When I start up httpd I get the following error

```
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:882
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

Comment: Looks like 882 is already in use by some other process on same server. Also make sure you have SUDO access on the server.

Comment: Thats what I had thought. BUT I did netstat -pln and scanned for 882 and did not find it in use.

Comment: change the port in httpd-ssl.conf to some other than 882..keep it as 443 and try. you are asking apache to listen on port 882 twice..

Comment: That allowed httpd to be started. But Im unsure if its the correct configuration. I changed the Listen and <VirtualHost _default_: in the httpd-ssl.conf file to 885.

Comment: https requests will try to look for 443 port on your apache server so the request will never be served if 443 is not configured. I would suggest instead of 885 configure 443 in httpd-ssl.conf

Comment: I believe port 443 is already in use on this server.